# How to use python to get the current commit of its own github repository

Tags: python, git, github

I have a github repository for a largish python project. The project is installed with [setup tools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), and it would be handy if, when `setup.py install` is called, it were able to introspect and set a project variable to the current commit being installed.

ie. it'd be handy to be able to do this

```
git clone https://github.com/u/project.git
cd /path/to/project
sudo python setup.py install

python
import project
print project.last_commit
>> 25jnrpf8pqijfq49sdsfjsj09sdf0sfjsdfkjs
```

It's not at all important that setup tools be used to get this information; I'm quite content to write a little script to modify the source before it installs.

I also realize this is probably a terrible idea, since I'd be immediately changing the local repository to no longer, in fact, *be* the ostensible commit, but, the only other way I can think to do this is by manually  updating the `last_commit` variable manually and, of course, never forgetting to have done this.

Mostly I'm just curious if this can be done without being too painful.

Comment: Why not use a subprocess call to git and then set a global variable? `git log --pretty -1` gives a really nice summary of the last commit and can be easily customized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted way to get your current git commit hash in a shell is `git rev-parse HEAD` (or `git rev-parse --short HEAD` if you want), so it would probably be best to simply [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for that string.